# Number(10) to/from int converion in SOCI/Oracle

Tags: c++, oracle, type-conversion, soci

I have encountered a problem when trying to convert between NUMBER(10) data type of Oracle DB and int(soci::dt_integer). The problem is that the integer range is within NUMBER(10) although NUMBER(10) is actually dt_long_long.

When I try to convert values using soci type conversions [`values.get<int>()`] it gives an exception when the column type is NUMBER(10). And if I change it to `values.get<long long>()` data writing cannot be done to a NUMBER(6 or so) types.

These conversion are working correctly when calling soci session statements directly. But it is not working when I try to try a custom type conversion for a class.

When I try to read the column data type, a soci_error "Rowset is empty" is thrown. Have anyone encountered this problem?

Thanks.